# No signature of method error after running flutter build appbundle

Tags: flutter, build.gradle

I'm trying to build an app bundle for a flutter project, and ran "flutter build appbundle." However, I get the following error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> - Where:
>   Build file '/Users/noah/Documents/wildtrack_app/android/app/build.gradle' line: 36

> - What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>   No signature of method: build_5nfu1zfyvrlq5vvix8fftxpa7.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_5nfu1zfyvrlq5vvix8fftxpa7$_run_closure2) values: [build_5nfu1zfyvrlq5vvix8fftxpa7$_run_closure2@59991e25]

This is the android block of the build.gradle file (line 36, where it says the error was):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.wildtrack.WildTrackAI"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName 1
        manifestPlaceholders = ['appAuthRedirectScheme': 'com.example.wildtrackapp']
    }


signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `flutter clean && flutter pub get` **after making sure that you are in the project's root directory**

If this doesn't work, make sure you've the following code before your `android { }` block

Example :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ...
}
```

And then run the `flutter clean && flutter pub get` again

If the issue still exists, check the path of the keystore.jks file